# Compilation in JSP

Tags: jsp

During compilation of a JSP file, it will be first converted into a .java file then .class file after that it will be loaded by the container to serve request. I want to know where container put converted .java and .class file. will it be available after request has been fulfilled.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using tomcat then it would be in work directory:

```
tomcat
    work
        catalina
            localhost
                webappName/context
                    java package directories
                           xyz.java
```

Answer (score 1):

> During compilation of a JSP file, it will be first converted into a .java file then .class file after that it will be loaded by the container to serve request

The servlet container will compile JSP into a class extending `HttpServlet` and use it for the webapp's lifetime.

> Want to know where container put converted .java and .class file

You can find the generated source code in the application server's `work` directory. In for example in Tomcat,  `/work` directory.

> will it be available after request has been fulfilled.

On a JSP request, the servlet container will execute the compiled JSP class and send the generated output get displayed it in the web browser. Servlet container will have the file till the app's lifetime

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fa ur quick responses..

I am using Netbeans 8.0.. During compilation in JSP whether same work directory to know java file and class file?